# Actors in Clojure

Tags: clojure, actor

I am writing a utility in Scala that includes a "file copy" actor. I send file names to be copied and the actor does them one at a time.

How would I to do the same thing in Clojure using agents?

Comment: You might be interested in this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost ready to begin beta, just needs a few more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need to perform this using agents? because you want to copy them asynchronously? But if you still want to do this, you can use something like:

```
(do-all (for [x file-names] (send-off agent-name copy-function x)))
```

although, maybe it's better to use futures?

Comment: I thought the point of agents is that they maintain some state that can be **altered** by passing a function. I guess that if you do not care about the previous value, but simply want to use the agent to do some asynchronous work, you can pass a copy function that ignores the previous value.

Comment: Yes, sure - you can store some state data into agent

Comment: If you are not going to store a state in the agents then it is better to use a future to do the work asynchronously.

Comment: Using a `future` for each file to copy would make the copying asychronous, make it easy to block on each one (or specific ones you might want to wait for), and allow all multiple copies to be going on at once (which may or may not be what you want).  Sending multiple times to a single agent queues up the copy operations so that only one will be happening at any one time.

Comment: Using a `future` assumes that there is no interaction between the file copies, or all such interaction is thread-safe (it may not be if the copying relies on Java interop). Using an Actor/Agent makes no such assumption because the copies are made sequentially, just not in the same thread as the sender.